# CSS: hyphens:auto if word-wrap not possible

Tags: html, css

In a dropdown menu, I have the two different situations:

One menu item has multiple words and it should break after a word.
The other menu item has one long word and it should break with auto hyphens

```
white-space: pre-line;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Result:

```
This item breaks
like it should

ThisItemDoesNotBre
akLikeItShould
```

This breaks the multiple-words-item as it should and breaks the one-word-item at the end of the menu-item. Adding a

```
hyphens:auto
```

makes the one-word-item look great, but the multiple-words-item does also break inside a word instead at the end of the word like before:

```
This item doesn't bre-
ak like it should

ThisItemDoesBreak-
LikeItShould
```

Is it possible to make hyphens:auto happen only to those menu items that cannot break after a word?

Answer (score 2):

The CSS rule you are using breaks the word according to the length of the word and not according to the "words" inside your one long word.

The browser will know to break the word in the correct place only if it knows which language you're using and a dictionary is available.

> Hyphenation rules are language-specific. In HTML, the language is determined by the lang attribute, and browsers will hyphenate only if this attribute is present and if an appropriate hyphenation dictionary is available. On XML, the xml:lang attribute must be used.
>    [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens)

If each word starts with a capital letter, you can try to separate your long word with Javascript/JQuery.

Comment: I tried to avoid using javascript for that task, but it does not seem to be as simple as I thought. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to add the language attribute? `<html lang="en">`